# notepad++ wildcard how to replace php code including an SESSION array

Tags: php, notepad++

**Hello there!**
So i'm currently programming with PHP and i need to replace code that includes an array which means **i'm in need of using a wildcard** for this.. I researched a bit but didn't find any solution that worked well

**i need to replace this:**

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['saved'][x][x]))
```

**with:**

```
if($_SESSION['saved'][x][x] != 0)
```

***x are numbers from 1-9**

I need a wildcard for these both

```
[x][x]
```

Comment: 0 != empty i think.

Comment: You are doing this in notepad++ or PHP? `1-9` in regex is `[1-9]` I'm not clear what you're trying to do though

Comment: hello thanks for the fast reply [x][x] are filled with numbers all over the code so for example: if(!empty($_SESSION['saved'][2][3])) and i need to replace each if(!empty($_SESSION['saved'][x][x])) and for that i need to use notepads++ wildcard but i dont know how i can simply make it work so in the example [2][3] needs to be a placeholder instead; im coding with notepad++ php/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can use a regular expression replace (select the `Regular expression` radio button at the bottom left of the `Replace` tab) to achieve this. Search for

```
if\s*\(!empty\((\$_SESSION\['saved'\]\[[1-9]\]\[[1-9]\])\)\)
```

and replace with

```
if \($1 != 0\)
```